# Multiple websites on one docker engine

Tags: docker

I made several containers running webapps but they are all running on different ports.

Now I want to link each container to there own domainname without the port.

Like this:
App A container
www.appacontainer.com

App B container
www.appbcontainer.com

What is the best way to go? Setting up a container with a DNS server inside or can I directly link the domainname to a container ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your website uses HTTP/HTTPS, the best way to do this would be to use the `Host` header field (which is required in all requests) to direct requests to the correct webapp. This is the same method by which subdomains are able to run on the same port as one another. I don't know exactly how Docker works, to be honest, but this would be the general idea.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it when a got home. Didn't knew you could use ports in the host file thought it was only for host name resolution?